# How to use For Loop to Replace Offset Cell

Tags: vba, excel

So I wrote a For Loop code that tries to search through a particular column (Column M) of data for cells containing a description starting with "GE90" and replaces an adjecent offset cell (Column C) with "GE90 Hold".

I thought I was using the code correctly but for some reason it does not seem to work.

```
Dim Cell
For Each Cell In Range("M2:M" & LastRow)
    If Cell.Value = "GE90*" Then
        Cell.Offset(, -10).Value = "GE90 Hold"
    End If

Next Cell
```

Comment: If I understand *starting with "GE90"* correctly, should you be using `If Left(Cell.Value, 4) = "GE90" Then`? The offset does seem correct to go from column M to column C (e.g. -10).

Comment: @Jeeped This code works perfectly Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Cell.Offset(, -10).Value` if you want to write to `Col C` is correct but why not a simplistic approach?

```
Range("C" & cell.row).Value = "GE90 Hold"
```

or

```
Cells(cell.row, 3).value '<~~ As enderland suggested in the comment
```

The problem is with your If condition. Change it to

```
If Cell.Value Like "GE90*" Then
```

Comment: Or `Cells(3, cell.row).value`

Comment: @enderland: Yup that too :) Updated my answer. :)

Comment: You might enjoy this chatroom btw - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba

Comment: @enderland: Just spotted a small typo in your code :) I have rectified that. `Cells(3, cell.row).value` should be `Cells(cell.row,3).value`

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Changing the = to Like solved the problem thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is actually that you assume the asterisk in `"GE90*"` is a wildcard, but actually, your code is looking for the literal value `"GE90*"`. Change your code as follows:

```
Dim Cell
For Each Cell In Range("M2:M" & lastrow)
    If Left(Cell.Value, 4) = "GE90" Then
        Cell.Offset(, -10).Value = "GE90 Hold"
    End If

Next Cell
```

Comment: Thanks! Changing the = to Like as Siddharth suggested solved all of my problems tho!

Comment: + 1 for adding the extra explanation about wildcards :)